# See what kind of access one has to a resource

Tags: windows-7, permissions

Maybe I was dreaming, but recently I thought I saw an interface that would allow one to enter a filename and user name and that interface would then display a detailed report of the rights that user had to that file based on what groups they belonged to and such. It would even illustrate why different rights were overridden.

As I'm writing this, I'm thinking I might have seen this in a visual 2012 preview, but I'm hoping maybe I saw this somewhere else available in windows. If anyone has any ideas I would much appreciate it. Thanks